# 3.5 male to IR Transmitter - Receiver [amplified] back to 3.5 female

Tags: infrared, diy, headphones

Trying to recreate a DIY headphone with IR transmitter and receiver

I already searched this is what I have found so far:
1.- http://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Infrared-transmitter-for-iPhone-iPod/ [For only the transmitter]
2.- [Connecting Headphone Jack to Amplifier Help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/282949/connecting-headphone-jack-to-amplifier-help) [For the troubles I might have amplifying the signal]
Based on [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DtCwJU6YMaA] if you don't want to check the whole video, basically some buddy is using 3.5 connected to a laser beaming through a photovoltaic panel which is connected to an amplifier and streaming music by this method with enough quality at half a mile distance.

The problem, basically is: I can do the same, connect 3.5 to IR LED and a LED IR receiver listening it, so I plug the headphones as wireless DIY headphones but i need to amplify it. Do you think I can mix 1 and 2 projects, and that little amplifier on the second link, is suitable to be feed by a AA or AAA battery so I can make this portable?

Comment: No I doubt you can do that.  Where is the  playback an audio track with infrared timings?  You can't just put 19kHz carrier with audio quality on it ot can you drive LEDs with audio, that would just full wave rectify the audio and sound terrible.

Comment: This is completely infeasible with leds.

Comment: @Passerby But why had this buddy done it on the youtube video link i gave? Isnt it just very similar?